# Conversion: NSString to NSDate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

This is a really common question, but mine might be unique since I have long decimal places for the seconds.

```
NSString *timestamp = @"2015-11-06 15:27:34.0000000";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss zzz"];
NSDate *capturedStartDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString: timestamp];
```

My `capturedStartDate` is null.

For the date format, I've tried replacing `zzz` with `Z`, `a`, and removing it completely. I've also tried with and without the `'T'`.  Does someone know the correct format to retrieve this date from the string?

Comment: `[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"];` I don't think there's any point to capturing more decimal points. Next time, consider reading the docs: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Comment: @matt I'm not capturing this date from the iOS app, I'm receiving it from a database.  This is just the format I have to deal with since that is the way it has been stored.  I agree, milliseconds can be pointless.

Comment: My point was that beyond three decimal places, NSDate won't differentiate. It doesn't have that degree of precision. Therefore, `".SSS"` is all the S's you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your date string doesn't have a time zone in it, so you should remove that `Z`. Also, you have fractions of a second, too. And there's no `T` in the date string. So you want

```
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS
```

This does beg the question as to what time zone that string represents. If it is UTC, you'll want to set the time zone of the formatter, accordingly.

Likewise, you might want to be careful about users with non-Gregorian calendars. See [Apple Technical Q&A 1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1480/_index.html) regarding setting the `locale` to `en_US_POSIX`.

Comment: Thats it, also I had to remove the `'T'` if I do not remove it then the date would return null

Comment: Agreed. The `T` should be removed, too.